# Como escalar imagenes con canvas a modo de background

Tags: android, bitmap, canvas

Intento poner un `Background` en la app, algo muy sencillo para aprender el uso de `canvas` y `bitmaps`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(new Vista(this));
}

public class Vista extends View{

    public Vista(Context context ){
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Paint mipincel = new Paint();
        Bitmap res = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.grassbg1);
        res.

        canvas.drawBitmap(res,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Bien, yo entiendo que con `canvas.drawBitmap(res,0,0,null)` estoy situando mi imagen en el punto(0,0) del `canvas` que he creado, pero claro la imagen no ocupa toda la pantalla(supongo que por el tamaño que tiene y demás), que metodo o que tipo de esacalado debo de hacer para conseguir que ocupe todo el fondo, y claro , que esté escalado para cualquier tipo de pantalla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código te servirá

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    int nuevoWidth;
    int nuevoHeight;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    nuevoWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    nuevoHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    Paint mipincel = new Paint();

    Bitmap res = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.grassbg1);
    Bitmap escalado = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(res, nuevoWidth, nuevoHeight, false);

    canvas.drawBitmap(escalado,0,0,null);
}
```